# How to forward a request as it is using Azure logic app without defining schema

Tags: azure, stripe-payments, webhooks, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app which gets some data from stripe. I want to forward request to some other api based on some property. Is it possible to just pass the request without defining
schema. Is there any other way to just forward the request as it is without any modifications to data ?
[image]

Comment: In your screenshot there you have "When a HTTP request is received"  so you want that request you got to be forwarded to another endpoint?

Comment: What exactly is the problem though?

Comment: yes @RickyGummadi. but is there way to pass without defining schema

Comment: @Skin stripe webhook signature is failing as it is expecting the exact format how stripe forwards. if  i am binding to the schema i defined it is appending /r or /n to json . which is why i dont want to bind to some predefined schema instead pass as it is.

Comment: Have you tried not having a schema at all?  I think that's permitted.

Comment: when you say forward, you need passing just the body or also all the headers ?

Comment: just body is fine @Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the calling application to ignore the schema you've defined, you can turn this setting off ...

[image: Schema Validation]

... alternatively, remove the schema entirely.  You don't actually need on but it does do is help you with subsequent actions where the values are strongly defined.

Comment: Thanks @Skin. Even though it didn't resolve my case but this is what I was looking for